# Retrieving json with an index value in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift

I have a json file

```
"result": {
"28086259": { 
  "uid": "28266107",
  "pubdate": "2017 Jan 13",
  "epubdate": "2017 Jan 13",
  }
"28238810": {
  "uid": "28238810",
  "pubdate": "2017 Feb 23",
  "epubdate": "2017 Feb 23",
  }
```

And I am trying to access each object using their codes i.e 28266107. I can access the values individually with the following code. idList contains a list of all the uid's.

```
  let parsedResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
  as! NSDictionary

      guard let results = parsedResult!["result"] as? [String:AnyObject] else {                   
                print("There was an error at result")
                return 
            }
      guard let id = results["\(self.idList[0])"] as? [String:AnyObject] else {
                print(error.debugDescription as Any)
                print("There was an error at id")
                return 
                    }
```

However If I try to create a for loop to parse uid into the results parameter the guard statement fails.

```
 for (index, element) in self.idList.enumerated() { 
      guard let id = results["\(element)"] as? [String:AnyObject] else {
                print(error.debugDescription as Any)
                print("Element at index \(element)")
                print("There was an error at id")
                return 
                    }
 }
```

The value of element when the guard fails is 28266107 which is the first value in the list.

I don't understand why looping through the guard statement will succeed if the idList array value is set to 0 but will fail if it is set to the value of an index. Especially when the index value is the exact same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through `Array` you need to loop through the result `Dictionary` and access the nested `Dictionary`.

```
if let parsedResult = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) a? [String:Any],
   let resultDic = parsedResult["result"] as? [String:[String:Any]] {

     for (key, value) in resultDic { 
         print(key) //If you want to access key also
         print(value["uid"])
         print(value["pubdate"])
         print(value["epubdate"])
     }
}
```

**Note:** You can also change `resultDic` type to `[String:[String:String]]` if all the value is of type `String` in the nested dictionary.

Comment: Yeah it's working. You solution actually allowed me to isolate the issue which was preventing my code from working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NiravD can i get the values as `print(value[0])` by refering index only??

Comment: @iOSDeveloper you can get the values as print(value[0]) only if your value is array